# radiobuttonlist selectedindexchanged event firing unexpected

Tags: asp.net, events, viewstate, init, radiobuttonlist

I have a `radiobuttonlist` I change the selected item in `codebehid`

```
private void DisplayPrivacyTerms(long ImageId)
{
    if (ImageryDataAccess.GetImagePrivacyTerm(ImageId).ToLower() == "me only")
    {
        RadioButtonListPrivacy.Items[0].Selected = true;
    }
    if (ImageryDataAccess.GetImagePrivacyTerm(ImageId).ToLower() == "friends")
    {
        RadioButtonListPrivacy.Items[1].Selected = true;
    }
    if (ImageryDataAccess.GetImagePrivacyTerm(ImageId).ToLower() == "public")
    {
        RadioButtonListPrivacy.Items[2].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

when the selected item is changed the above way, then later `postback` to the server triggers the `selectedindexchanged` event.
Especially I have `listview` which displays `imagebuttons`. When I click the imagebutton in the `listview` and if the selected item is changed then the later click on imagebutton triggers the `selectedinexchanged` event of `radiobuttonlist`..
why is this happening I don't expect this will trigger this event..

Comment: question is too vague to understand? please be a bit more specific.

Comment: actually the issue is that of changing the selected item programmatically. how to change the radiobuttonlist.items[].selected property effectively? when it triggers the selectedindexchanged event?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. But seems like you need to handle some logic on the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of your `RadioButtonList`

First set the `AutoPostBack="true"` property on your `RadioButtonList`

Then on the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event, write your logic.

```
protected void RadioButtonListPrivacy_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
   // your logic here
   // so basically when you click on any of the items in your radiobuttonlist,
   // this event will fire and you can write your logic based on it  
}
```

Comment: wHEN I CHANGE THE SELECTED=TRUE PROPETY THEN ON CLICKING OTHER BUTTONS THAT POSTSBACK TO SERVER TRIGGERS THIS EVENT...

Comment: Check my own answer above and tell me exactly how the viewstate is doing that trick? I am still not sure what was exactly wrong

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue was that I had initialized the items declaratively in the aspx page. I changed the function in trouble to code like the following

```
    private void DisplayPrivacyTerms(long ImageId)
      {
    RadioButtonListPrivacy.Items.Clear();
    ListItem itemMe= new ListItem("Me Only", "1");
    RadioButtonListPrivacy.Items.Add(itemMe);
    ListItem itemMates = new ListItem("Subject Mates", "2");
    RadioButtonListPrivacy.Items.Add(itemMates);
    ListItem itemPublic = new ListItem("Public", "3");
    RadioButtonListPrivacy.Items.Add(itemPublic);

    if (ImageryDataAccess.GetImagePrivacyTerm(ImageId).ToLower() == "me only")
    {
        RadioButtonListPrivacy.Items[0].Selected = true;
    }
    if (ImageryDataAccess.GetImagePrivacyTerm(ImageId).ToLower() == "subject mates")
    {
        RadioButtonListPrivacy.Items[1].Selected = true;
    }
    if (ImageryDataAccess.GetImagePrivacyTerm(ImageId).ToLower() == "public")
    {
        RadioButtonListPrivacy.Items[2].Selected = true;
    }

}
```

I cleared the list and then added new entries that way it cleared the viewstate issue that was arising with just changing the Select=true property.. :)